# How to get Bittrex Commission Value from API

Tags: bittrex

Binance has a very simple way of getting the Commission value from its exchangeInfo endpoint.

I do not see any corresponding way to get the commission on Bittrex from the API documentation, but it is relatively poor documentation and only covers v1.1

Does anyone know how to get the Commission value from the API?

(Note, I know the current value is 0.25%, which is currently hardcoded into my scripts. I'd prefer to fetch the current value in case it changes rather than rely on hardcoding the value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the latest [Bittrex Beta documentation](https://github.com/Bittrex/beta), there is a JSON key called "CommissionPaid", minified to "n", which would indicate how much commission was paid on a trade. From my experience, it would seem that only the new beta websocket API provides this information, which means you'd have to subscribe to that and check the feed for this value.

A comment from someone associated with the Bittrex API, at the Github link posted above, indicates that he does not believe the REST API will undergo changes, so with that, I would not expect for this key to be transferred to the REST version.